# not getting a diffrent price getting a same price for every pic not getting different id on caption

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div id="products" class="row list-group">

         <?php $counter = 1; foreach ($photo_products as $value) { 
                $product = new WC_Product( $value->ID ); ?>
    <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img class="myImg" class="group list-group-image" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($value->ID, array(324, 324)); ?>" alt="" />
            <div class="caption">
                <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                   <?php echo esc_attr($product->get_title()); ?></h4>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <p class="lead">
                           <?php echo wc_price($product->get_price()); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <a class="btn btn-success " href="<?php echo esc_attr($current_url).'/?add-to-cart='.esc_attr($value->ID); ?>">
                            <?php esc_html_e('Add to cart', 'woocommerce-photography-plugin'); ?>

                            </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                     <span class="close">&times;</span>
                  <img id="img01" class="modal-content"  src="">
                    <div id="caption"  class="modal-content">
                        <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                   <?php echo esc_attr($product->get_title()); ?></h4>
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <p class="lead" >
                           <?php echo wc_price($product->get_price()); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <a class="btn btn-success " href="<?php echo esc_attr($current_url).'/?add-to-cart='.esc_attr($value->ID); ?>">
                            <?php esc_html_e('Add to cart', 'woocommerce-photography-plugin'); ?>

                            </a>

                    </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>

    </div>


        <?php $counter++; } ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: My issue is that i am not same price for every same the first image which was display

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document. By outputting this code in a loop, you are generating `<div id="myModal"` multiple times, and that _will_ break things when it comes to triggering these modals.

Comment: so then what i do did i made a model out side the loop

Comment: If you want multiple different modals, you need to output them with different IDs. (For example by appending a loop counter to a static prefix.) And then you need to modify the places that are supposed to trigger a specific modal as well.

Comment: i dont want multiple different model i want one which display all my images with price and title

Comment: now what you suggest

Comment: Well if you don’t want multiple modals, then you must not output the code for the modal inside a loop that runs multiple times. If you want to output data from multiple records inside a single modal - then the loop over that data belongs _“into”_ the modal to begin with. Output `<div id="myModal" class="modal">`, loop over data to output the data from multiple records, output `</div>` to close the modal _after_ the loop …

Comment: i wirte a loop inside a modal but now it display all titles and all price on every image when i click on that image

Comment: i write a for loop

Comment: what you suggest now

Comment: How are you triggering the modal? I don’t see a `data-toggle="modal"` or a `data-target` anywhere. If you are calling this yourself somehow via JS, we need to see how.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = $('.myImg');
var modalImg = $("#img01");
var captionText =$('.caption');
$('.myImg').click(function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    var newSrc = this.src;
    modalImg.attr('src', newSrc);
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
});


var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

Comment: thats my script

Comment: So it triggers on all elements that match the `.myImg` selector. Whether that is what you want or not, rather impossible to tell right now, because we don’t know what HTML structure you are currently creating.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$product = new WC_Product( $value->ID );
```

You can try, following code:

```
$product = WC_Product::find()->where('id'=>$value->ID);
```